# Python Pandas: Is there a way to obtain a subset dataframe based on strings in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am looking to make a subset df based on the string values in a list.

A toy model example:

```
data = {'month': ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'],
        'days_in_month': [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['month', 'days_in_month'])

summer_months = ['Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb']

contain_values = df[df['month'].str.contains(summer_months)] 
print (df)
```

This would fail because of `contain_values = df[df['month'].str.contains(summer_months)]`

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I know that `contain_values = df[df['month'].str.contains('Dec')]` works but I would like to return the new `dataframe` with the summer months in it. Or even all the none summer months using the `~` function.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
>>> contain_values = df[df['month'].str.contains('|'.join(summer_months))]

>>> contain_values
       month  days_in_month
0    January             31
1   February             28
11  December             31
```

Answer (score 2):

You can as well using what `.str` offers you:

```
df[df["month"].str[:3].isin(summer_months)]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
       month  days_in_month
0    January             31
1   February             28
11  December             31
```

You can make it more robust using something like this (in case names in the dataframe are not properly capitalized):

```
df[df["month"].str.capitalize().str[:3]]
```